# How can I get thousands of data faster in Firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have developed an app where I get a list of users constantly updated as they enter the vicinity. It shows up fast & fine when there are a few users (roughly less than 100), but takes time when it crosses the mark.

Is there a particular way that I can get the list as soon as possible? It has a bunch of criteria where the list gets showed up, to which I am assuming it is taking that much time to load. What can I do here to optimise the time and get the list quickly?

Conditions of getting the "make friends" list is as follows:

1. The list of all the users who are not in friends with the current user
2. Both the users (current user and the other user who are not friends with each other) should be on the same venue they have booked the entry for
3. The entry is marked as "1" from the venue side once they enter the venue
4. (assuming the user can go to multiple venues on the same day) They should get the list of users, where the last entry is marked as 1

Comment: The question is vague. Saying *but takes time* and *get the list as soon as possible* doesm't really tell us what the issue is. For example, our app loads 10k friends in about a second. Is a second too long? Are we going to use all of them at the same time? Probably not! What's likely needed is a subset; ones that are within a mile radius, or that like pizza with cheese only. If you can include the code in your question that duplicates the issue, we may be of more help. Please review [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

To increase the performance, the best way is to put all data **related to the query** inside the same collection, in this case, the `user` collection.

Also, when you are not dealing with duplicated entries, prefer using maps instead of arrays, because it's better for Firebase Security Rules and performing queries, so it would be something like:

`user` document example:

```
{
    name: "John"
    friends: { 
       "<user-id-abc...>": true,
       "<user-id-def...>": true, 
       // undefined properties will be considered as "not friend"
    },
    venues: {
       lastVenue: "<venue-id-abc...>",
       "<venue-id-abc...>": true,
       "<venue-id-def...>": true,
    }
}
```

So I think the query would be something similar to this:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
   .collection("users")
   .where("friends.${friendId}", isNotEqualTo: true) // not friends
   .where("venues.lastVenue", isEqualTo: lastVenueId) // same last venue
   .get();
```

Or in Node.js:

```
db.collection("users")
    .where(`friends.${friendId}`, "!=", true) // not friends
    .where("venues.lastVenue", "==", lastVenueId) // same last venue
    .get();
```